# How to write tests for ASP.NET MVC 3 AsyncControllers with MSpec

Tags: testing, asp.net-mvc-3, bdd, mspec, asynccontroller

I want to write a `TaskController` for an ASP.NET MVC 3 application to some long running tasks, like sending a newsletter to the users of the site. I thought using an `AsyncController` would be appropriate as sending emails might take a while, and I want to be able to save some state to the database when the task finishes running.

Being the properly brought up developer that I am (:þ), and being  really into BDD, I naturally want to start off with a spec using MSpec.

Imagine my controller looks like this:

```
public class TaskController : AsyncController
{    
    readonly ISession _session;

    public TaskController(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public void SendMailAsync()
    {
        // Get emails from db and send them
    }

    public ActionResult SendMailCompleted()
    {
        // Do some stuff here
    }
}
```

How does one go about writing specs for AsyncControllers? Imagine I start with the following specification:

```
public class TaskControllerContext
{
    protected static Mock<ISession> session;
    protected static TaskController controller;
    protected static ActionResult result;
}

[Subject(typeof(TaskController), "sending email")]
public class When_there_is_mail_to_be_sent : TaskControllerContext
{
    Establish context = () =>
    {
        session = new Mock<ISession>();
        controller = new TaskController(session.Object);
    };

    // is this the method to call?
    Because of = () => controller.SendMailAsync();

    // I know, I know, needs renaming...
    It should_send_mail;
}
```

Should I be calling the `SendMailAsync` method for the test? I actually feels yucky.
How do I deal with the result from `SendMailCompleted`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I finally figured out at least a way to do it. I'm sure there are other and probably better ways, but here goes:

Declare an `AutoResetEvent` that will be used as wait handle and an `EventHandler` that will be set up to fire when the async action completes. Then in the `Because` block (corresponding to the `Act` part of unit testing) call `WaitOne` on the `AutoResetEvent`:

```
static AutoResetEvent waitHandle; 
static EventHandler eventHandler;
static int msTimeout = 5000;
static IEnumerable<Email> response;

Establish context = () =>
{
    toSend = new List<Email>
    {
        // Emails here
    };

    // Prepare the mock objects
    session.Setup(x => x.All<Email>()).Returns(toSend.AsQueryable());
    mailer.Setup(x => x.SendMail(Moq.It.IsAny<IEnumerable<Email>>()))
        .Returns(toSend);

    // Set up the wait handle    
    waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    eventHandler = (sender, e) => waitHandle.Set();
    controller.AsyncManager.Finished += eventHandler;
};

Because of = () =>
{
    controller.SendMailAsync();
    if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(msTimeout, false)) {}

    response = (IEnumerable<Email>) controller.AsyncManager
        .Parameters["sentMails"];
};

It should_send_mail = () => response.Any().ShouldBeTrue();
```

This should work as well if you're writting unit tests with NUnit or any other test framework instead of MSpec.